# Oracle no results, small query

Tags: sql, oracle, isnull

I am having trouble with some sql. When I run the following query:

```
Select * from teleapp;
```

I get TONS of results. Resulst which include a column (called cashwithappyn) that has TONS of empty or null data cells. (They look empty and don't say null)

The column info is:

```
ColumnName      ID          Null? Data Type             Histogram   Num Distinct  Num Nulls    Density
CASHWITHAPPYN   54          Y     VARCHAR2(1 Byte)      Frequency   2             56895         0
```

When I try to run the following query:

```
Select * from teleapp where cashwithappyn = null;
```

or

```
Select * from teleapp where cashwithappyn = '';
```

or

```
Select * from teleapp where cashwithappyn not like '';
```

or

```
Select * from teleapp where cashwithappyn not in ('Y','N');
```

or ANY type of combination, I cannot seem to get all of the rows with nothing in cashwithappyn.

Any ideas? Please help, this is the last part of a project that I was assigned to do and I just need to figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: `where cashwithappyn is null OR cashwithappyn = ''` perhaps?

Comment: This is a trivial syntax question which is answered in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements005.htm#sthref470

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the column contains blanks. In that case you can do

```
WHERE TRIM(CASHWITHAPYYN) IS NULL
```

`TRIM` removes all blanks before and after and if nothing is left anymore the value becomes `NULL`

e.g.

```
TRIM(' ') IS NULL -- one blank removed = true
TRIM(NULL)  IS NULL -- true
```

Also `NULL` cannot be compared with `= NULL` but must be phrased `IS NULL`. `NULL` is not a value as such and that is why the comparison never works.

Comment: I understand about the is null thing. I was just trying every possible combination and nothing was working.

Actually, trim did work :O Thanks man :) I'll mark yours as the correct answer too.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use IS NULL

```
Select * from teleapp where cashwithappyn is null;
```

Comment: Then they must not be null, there must be spaces or some other non visible characters

Comment: You could use LENGTH(cashwithappyn) in your select to confirm there's something in the field.

Comment: There is nothing returned with length :(

Comment: Length will return either a number or null, what do you mean nothing is returned?

Comment: The cells are still empty, so I assume it's null. Others which contain a Y or N do return 1

Comment: Where are you running the query?  Go back to SQL+ or SQL Developer and run it there so you can see the actual results.

Answer (score 4):

Logical test expressions (=, Not In, Like etc) with null result in a false so all of the following result in false

```
1 = NULL
1 <> NULL
NULL = NULL
NULL <> NULL
NULL NOT IN ('a','b')
NULL Not Like NULL
```

Additionally in oracle the zero length string is null so `NOT LIKE ''` will never return any rows

You'll need to use either `is null`, `is not null` or `Coalesce`

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker and I did a bunch of research, here's what we came up with that will work. Any ideas why this works but not the others?

```
Select * from teleapp where nvl(cashwithappyn,'U') = 'U';
```

Comment: So you are saying that in your case `where nvl(cashwithappyn,'U') = 'U'` works and `where cashwithappyn is null` doesn't?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I am saying.